# Retrieving stored procedure script and parameters separately

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I want to access the stored procedure script using C#.

I used `EXEC sp_HelpText STOREDPROCNAME`. This is working fine.

Is there any way to retrieve stored procedure query and the stored procedure parameter separately??

ex: I need:

```
delete from [dbo].[tblTransactions] where [ID] = @ID
```

and

```
@ID numeric(18,0)
```

separately.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the body this way, but there isn't a way to parse out the individual statements:

```
SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.procedurename');
```

You can get its parameters by:

```
SELECT name, system_type_id, max_length, precision, scale
FROM sys.parameters
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.procedurename');
```

Note that you can't determine without brute force parsing of the definition whether the parameters have a default value, and if they do, what the default value is. You are better equipped to do these things in C# using RegEx or other parsing methods, or PowerShell like [the ParamParser project I started here](https://github.com/AaronBertrand/ParamParser).

Comment: the parameter part is working fine. as u told the statement part is coming as it is.. Any other way? at least in C# code?

Comment: Unfortunately, since so many syntax styles are possible, it is going to be very difficult for you to determine where the body of the procedure begins and ends, and where individual statements within the procedure begin and end. Go ahead and write a RegEx that pulls out a single statement from within a procedure, and I'll write a procedure that breaks it. :-)

Comment: It's insane that this returns columns [has_default_value] and [default_value] but they aren't populated.  Seems you have to use the SMO objects to get this information.

Comment: @tbone I agree, I filed a Connect item nearly a decade ago and it's still not been addressed. Please comment and vote! https://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=234143

Comment: "Don't ascribe to malice that which can be explained by incompetence" they say - I don't know why, but I swear sometimes Microsoft **enjoys** hurting their customers.  This would be SO easy to fix once and for all, and it would make certain things so much easier.  It just boggles the mind.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to ask the db directly with [`SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx)

> Retrieves parameter information from the stored procedure specified in
>   the SqlCommand and populates the Parameters collection of the
>   specified SqlCommand object.

There is also

`exec [dbname].[sys].[sp_procedure_params_rowset] @procedure_name=N'uspblabla'`

the source of which you can see via `sp_helptext sp_procedure_params_rowset`.

Comment: then how about the statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo and use code similar to the following:

```
void Main()
{
    Server server = new Server("server");
    Database db = server.Databases["database"];

    string sprocName = "StoredProcName";

    StoredProcedure proc = db.StoredProcedures[sprocName];
    if (proc != null)
    {
        foreach (StoredProcedureParameter parameter in proc.Parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:  {1}", parameter.DataType.Name, parameter.Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(proc.TextBody);
    }
}
```

Additional information can be found [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx)