# SQL statement to retrieve procedure optional parameters list

Tags: sql-server

I am creation dynamic SQL generation for db objects. But for validation purposes i need to verify is all non optional arguments (parameters) was provided to avoid sql error.

Is there any way to retrieve list of all optional arguments (parameters) for Stored procedure or Function?

Example:
Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestSP
    @prm1 int,
    @prm2 int = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```

Query i use to retrieve list of arguments (parameters):

```
select 
  pa.name as [ParameterName], 
  t.[name] as [ParameterDataType], 
  LTRIM(RTRIM(o.type)) as [ObjType],
  pa.has_default_value as [HasDefaultValue],
  pa.default_value as [DefaultValue]
from sys.objects (nolock) o
inner join sys.schemas (nolock) s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
left join sys.parameters (nolock) AS pa  on pa.object_id = o.object_id
left join sys.types (nolock) t on t.user_type_id = pa.user_type_id
where o.[name] = N'TestSP'
order by pa.parameter_id asc;
```

For some reasons **sys.parameters.has_default_value** and **sys.parameters.default_value** do not display actual declaration of argument (parameter)

Comment: Why are you using `NOLOCK` against system tables? That suggests you have a habit of abusing the query hint.

Comment: @Hogan By using it blindly on every single object, and perhaps doing so while [not knowing the risks](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6072/sql-server-nolock-anomalies-issues-and-inconsistencies/). And if you're applying it to every object in a query, it's better to set the isolation level in a single place than pepper `NOLOCK` throughout the query - not only does the query become easier to read, but it also makes it easier to change/remove later when you get bitten by one of the nasty side effects.

Comment: Using `NOLOCK` for **every** object in **every** query *is* abuse of the query hint, @Hogan . It clearly means the OP doesn't understand what it means. Bertrand has done a wonderful article on why you shouldn't do it: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Hogan I think everyone on a technical Q & A site can distinguish between "abusing the query hint" and abuse in the real world. Just like when I say `UNION` nobody thinks we're talking about a plumbers' organization or when I say `master` nobody thinks we're talking about slavery.

Comment: @Hogan unfortunately I can assure you that you are wrong on that people *don't* use it wrong. Almost any query you see on Stack Overflow, where a user has littered it with `NOLOCK` is a clear sign that they don't understand it, and are using it wrong. The amount of times I've heard here that they are using it to "stop locks" or "because the company says that must" is countless...

Comment: @Larnu don't forget "to make it faster."

Comment: It *is* the magic "go faster" button, after all, @AaronBertrand . ;)

Comment: @Hogan So are we, but it's not because when we say `master database` people are confused.

Comment: @Larnu nolock's is kinda habit (bad one) related to quite frequent usage because of need to retrieve dirty data. But they do not impact on issue in any way.

Comment: Also unrelated to the problem, but `LTRIM(RTRIM(o.type))` has me scratching my head a bit too. Why do you need to trim leading and trailing spaces from a `char(2)`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, well yes, LTRIM is unnecessary here, but in case if object type is Procedure (P) for example query returns 2 chars always (letter and CHAR(32))

Comment: But why is that a problem? Do you think it costs more to transmit that single byte than it does to _try to remove it_ on _every single row_? If it's about cosmetics, I would have the presentation layer remove it, but I doubt that is necessary in most cases anyway.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Well yes, even for quite slow network its not efficient. Ill remove this from legacy app. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you will need to parse the `OBJECT_DEFINITION()` manually to determine the default values, or peek into SSMS to trace what it does to show even just whether or not there is a default value (never mind what the value is).

The catalog view never populates those columns except for CLR modules. [I filed this issue back in 2006](http://web.archive.org/web/20130726131248/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=234143), and it has never been addressed (though it was [brought over to the new feedback system](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/ac92cf2b-6025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)).

I talked about the issue in [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/08/01/connect-digest-2009-08-01), which also references a different Connect item that did not get preserved by the wayback machine. That item did, however, [make it over to the new site](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c4f93aea-4c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0).

The blog post also mentions that I once tried to solve the issue through parsing, back when SQL Server Q & A mostly happened in newsgroups, but it is cumbersome and there are a lot of edge cases that make it a difficult problem to solve reliably. Also none of the usual places where you might find an archived copy of that post seem to have it any more, and it certainly no longer exists on any of my computers, though I did find [other references from that timeframe](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/c/1YgKje8GVhk/m/nZv9TQSNxiAJ).

Previous related Q & A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9720451/61305) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13897/1186).

#### Update October 2021

Earlier this year I did solve this problem with PowerShell and TSqlFragmentVisitor and threw it up in a GitHub repo:

- [Parse parameter default values using PowerShell – Part 1](https://sqlblog.org/2020/09/25/paramparser-1)
- [Parse parameter default values using PowerShell – Part 2](https://sqlblog.org/2020/10/01/paramparser-2)
- [Parse parameter default values using PowerShell – Part 3](https://sqlblog.org/2020/10/16/paramparser-3)
- [github.com/AaronBertrand/ParamParser](https://github.com/AaronBertrand/ParamParser)